# i am getting error when installing formik in react native

Tags: react-native

i am getting error when installing formik infact when I try  to install some thing I get error I have install by two way `npm install formit` and `npm i react-native-formik`
[image]

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder, and use `yarn` instead
And you should `--save` flag to your command to update dependencies-folder `npm install --save react-native-formik`

Answer (score 1):

Delete node_modules folder and run command npm install

Answer (score 0):

i used "npm install formik --save"
should work

Answer (score 0):

delete node modules and run "npm i formik" then "npm i" .... Hope this will work for u..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).